# Get date from a ms since epoch using Bash

Tags: json, bash, date

I have a json file which needs to be parsed . It has date in long format , sometimes negative long
Eg: `-201269509000` .  If i use this formula `t=$(date -d @-201269509000 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');` . This gives an answer like `-4408-01-10 00:56:48` .How do i sort this out ? I am trying to do this via shell script.

Comment: Use `date -d@201269509 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: it worked Great thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `date` expects numbers in epoch seconds, and your json output is *likely* in epoch ms (if you know that 4408 BCE is incorrect). Anubhava's comment is wrong, as it assumes your input is positive seconds since epoch.

```sh
seconds=-201269509000
t=$(date -d @${seconds%???} +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
echo $t
> 1963-08-16 04:48:11
```

`${var%???}` removes the last 3 characters from `$var`. This is an example of [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: cool . Thanks !! WOW! i just dont understand why have epoch time

Answer (score 0):

> *I have a json file*

Then you might as well use a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) that can parse JSON **and** can do date-conversions.

Let's say your JSON is `{"original_date":-201269509000}`.

To get the value of the `"original_date"` attribute:

```
xidel -s input.json -e '$json/original_date'
-2.01269509E11

xidel -s input.json -e '$json/integer(original_date)'
-201269509000
```

Convert (milli)seconds to UTC datetime:

```
xidel -s input.json -e '$json/integer(original_date div 1000)'
-201269509            # milliseconds to seconds

xidel -s input.json -e '$json/original_date div 1000 * duration("PT1S")'
-P2329DT12H11M49S     # seconds to duration (since 1970-01-01)

xidel -s input.json -e '$json/original_date div 1000 * duration("PT1S") + dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00")'
1963-08-16T11:48:11   # UTC datetime

#same as:
date -u -d @-201269509 +%FT%T
1963-08-16T11:48:11
```

Customize datetime-format:

```
xidel -s input.json -e '
  $json/original_date div 1000 * duration("PT1S") +
  implicit-timezone() + dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00")
'
1963-08-16T13:48:11   # localized datetime taking timezone into consideration

xidel -s input.json -e '
  $json/format-dateTime(
    original_date div 1000 * duration("PT1S") +
    implicit-timezone() + dateTime("1970-01-01T00:00:00"),
    "[Y]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]"
  )
'
1963-08-16 13:48:11
```

**note**: to use `implicit-timezone()` at least [`xidel-0.9.9.20200726.7433`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/videlibri/files/Xidel/Xidel%20development/) is needed.

Comment: im using jq for json parsing and don't understand why a learn a new tool , also the date conversions look complicated, anyways Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @DivyangShah if you wanted an answer with `jq`, then you should've tagged your question as such.